# How to override command cache:flush?

Tags: magento2

I want override command **cache:flush**. while execute this **php bin/magento cache:flush**
i want to execute my custom module code. can i do? please guide me on this.

**Note:** i'm try to use in magento 2.4.5-p1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, there are 2 ways.

1. If you want to create event observer, then create like this :

   ```
   <event name="adminhtml_cache_refresh_type">
        <observer name="youobservername" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\YourcustomerObserverFile"/>
    </event>
   ```
2. If you want plugin, then `cache:flush` command execute code from this methods.

`\Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushAll::execute()` method.

so try to create that class plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much for guide and help can you please guide me even and plugin for when i try to use this command.

module:disable
module:enable
module:status
module:uninstall

Comment: If above answer help you, accept and upvote, so that is help other in community. If you have seprate question ask seprately, we can help you there as well.

Comment: Ok thank you :)

Comment: Please guide here.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/364555/how-to-override-command-moduleuninstall-and-disable-enable-status