# How to override command module:uninstall and disable,enable,status?

Tags: magento2

I want override command **module:uninstall <module_name>**. while execute this **php bin/magento module:uninstall <module_name>** also in relevant command disable,enable,status

i want to execute my custom module code. can i do? please guide me on this.

**Note:** i'm try to use in magento 2.4.5-p1

Comment: why you donot create another custom command for your requirement?

Comment: @Amit Bera NO i can create but my requirement is when this command module:uninstall execute then i want execute my custom requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the file which called on particular command.

**module:uninstall**

> /magento
> root/vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/ModuleDisableCommand.php - execute method there

**module:status**

> /magento
> root/vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/ModuleStatusCommand.php - execute method there

**module:disable**

> /magento
> root/vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/ModuleDisableCommand.php

**module:enable**

> /magento
> root/vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/ModuleEnableCommand.php

Comment: i know this path. it's not my issue as i mention in my question.

Comment: Yes, but from there you get idea, for your requirement what you want to do.